# Проверка существования объекта с присваиванием

Tags: javascript

Каждый раз при написании универсальной функции для разных страниц, но с одной целью, возникает надобность проверки существования объекта на странице с последующем присвоением и работой с ним. Конструкция довольно однообразная и громоздкая:

```html
if(document.getElementById('modal')){
  modal=document.getElementById('modal');
  //дальше работа уже с существующим объектом
}
```

Существует ли более короткий вид данной записи?

P.S. Корректно ли будет присваивать в самом условии?

```html
<input type="text" value="5" id="inp">
    <script>
       if (inp=document.getElementById('inp')) { console.log(inp.value) }
    </script>
```

Comment: Эм, ну очевидный вариант `modal = document.getElementById('modal'); if (modal) { ... }`

Comment: Тогда в логах будет ошибка на попытку присвоить несуществующий элемент, если его вдруг нет на странице.

Comment: @IvanChuzhmakov не будет ошибки. Просто переменная получит значение **null** и в if проверка будет false и код не пойдет выполнятся.

Comment: Добавил в ТС-вопрос "Корректно ли будет присваивать в самом условии?"

Comment: По вашему второму примеру - сделать конечно можете и работать будет, однако, это не читабельно и принято, в if писать проверку, а не выполнять операции присвоения. [Почитайте, отдохните и оцените после прочтения код](https://learn.javascript.ru/ninja-code)

Comment: Спасибо за чтиво, доходчиво.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Решение 1

А что вам мешает создать его?

```js
/**
 * @template {typeof HTMLElement} T
 * @param {String} selectors 
 * @param {T} type 
 */
function getElement(selectors, type) {
    const element = document.querySelector(selectors);
    if (!(element instanceof type)) {
        throw new ReferenceError(`Element ${selectors} is missing or has invalid type`);
    }
    return (/** @type {InstanceType<T>} */ (element));
}

const header = getElement(`header`, HTMLElement);
const main = getElement(`main`, HTMLElement);
const inputUserName = getElement(`input#user-name`, HTMLInputElement);
```

```html
<header></header>
<main>
  <input id="user-name" type="text">
</main>
```

За одно, если у вас установлен TypeScript и поддержка JSDoc, произойдет и проверка типа:

[image]

#### Решение 2 ([@SwaD](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/520560))

Если не нужно при отсутствии элемента выкидывать ошибку, могу предложить вот такой подход:

```js
/**
 * @template {typeof HTMLElement} T
 * @param {String} selectors 
 * @param {T} type 
 * @param {(element: InstanceType<T>) => void} action 
 */
function checkElement(selectors, type, action) {
  const element = document.querySelector(selectors);
  if (element instanceof type) {
    action( /** @type {InstanceType<T>} */ (element));
  }
}

checkElement(`input#user-name`, HTMLInputElement, (element) => {
  // Действия с элементом
});
```

```html
<header></header>
<main>
  <input id="user-input" type="text">
</main>
```

Этот метод так же поддерживает типизацию:

[image]

#### Решение 3 ([@SwaD](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/520560))

Более компактный вариант не с самой лучшей типизацией:

```js
/**
 * @param {String} selectors 
 * @param {(element: HTMLElement) => void} action 
 */
function withElement(selectors, action) {
  const element = document.querySelector(selectors);
  if (element) action( /** @type {HTMLElement} */ (element));
}

withElement(`input#user-name`, (element) => {
  // Действия
})
```

```html
<header></header>
<main>
  <input id="user-input" type="text">
</main>
```

[image]

#### Решение 4 ([@StanislavVolodarskiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/416121))

Асинхронный вариант с `Promise`:

```js
/**
 * @param {String} selectors 
 * @returns {Promise<HTMLElement>}
 */
function atElement(selectors) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const element = document.querySelector(selectors);
    if (element) resolve( /** @type {HTMLElement} */ (element));
  });
}

atElement(`input#user-name`).then((element) => {
  // Действия
});
```

```html
<header></header>
<main>
  <input id="user-input" type="text">
</main>
```

#### Решение 5

Самый банальный, но ограниченный вариант:

```js
document.querySelector(`input#user-name`)?.setCustomValidity(`Invalid field`);
document.querySelector(`input#user-surname`)?.setCustomValidity(`Invalid field`);
```

```css
:invalid {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<input id="user-name" type="text">
```

Comment: Решение через чур мощное для вопроса... Да и стоит ли оно того? Мне кажется, что суть вопроса - как уложить все проверки с присвоением в одну строку с минимальным количеством символов

Comment: Ну... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ Лично у меня есть что-то подобное. Облегчает жизнь при написании проектов.

Comment: @SwaD после этой функции все проверки и присваивания будут в 1 строку :D

Comment: Неа... Судя по вопросу, после функции, надо проверить, что элемент есть и выполнить с ним код.

Comment: @SwaD добавил альтернативное решение для подмеченной вами задачи

Comment: Добавьте еще вариант без проверки на тип и будет огонь!

Comment: Колбек на промис обменять можно. Тогда можно будет писать линейный код даже для нескольких вложенных проверок.

Comment: @SwaD - добавил.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy тоже добавил

Comment: Интересные варианты решения данного вопроса. Конечно возможно они в той или иной степени верны или полезны, по этому я отмечу как решение, но для себя я понял, что моя запись не такая уж и громоздкая по сравнению с этими решениями). По данной аналогии, можно создать простую функцию в которую будет передаваться id элемента и проверять тем же if(document.getElementById(idElement)){return true;}else{return false;}